# Data post differ from Firefox-IE

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery to send the code in some `<pre>` tags of [my blog](http://www.felicepollano.com) to an handler, that will replace these with a proper pastebin.com frame containing the formatted code.

I'm using an MD5 hash to map the code chunk to the pastebin corresponding translation in order to have just one paste bin for each code snippet.

Problem is that the string posted seems to change a little between IE and firefox, so I don't have an exactly MD5 codification. For some reason problem appear only on the production server.

The jquery code is this:

```
$(function() {

    $.each($('pre'), function(i, e) {

        if (e.lang != '') {

            $.ajax({
                url: 'pastebin.ashx',
                context: $(this),
                data: {
                    data: $(this).text(),
                    lang: e.lang
                },
                success: function(t) {
                    if (t.indexOf('*error*') != 0) {
                        var h = Math.floor($(this).height() * 1.62) + "px";
                        $(this).replaceWith("<iframe src='http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=" + t + "' style='border:none;width:100%;height:" + h + "'></iframe>")
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    });

});​
```

Is there some reason the posted data can change from different browsers ?
**EDIT**

The problem does not happen with all the IE, same version 9.0.8112.16421 works on a machine, and not with another! I suppose the difference must be in the $(this).text(). Failing version seems to contain the text without carriage returns.

Comment: do you have some examples of the post send by ff and ie ?

Comment: @EvilP nope it happen just on the server in the shared host...

Comment: @FelicePollano EvilP means can you post what data is being sent in your AJAX call in both IE and FF.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It is just a plain portion of c# code, as I can see in the testable app.

Comment: @EvilP the failing version seems contain the code without carriage returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the solution: using `html()` instead of `text()` fixed the problem: the only drawback of using html() is that the pre content is htmlEncoded, so I had to modify the handler, but the result we obtain seems ro be stable across browsers.

Answer (score 2):

If the problem lies with the carriage return, why don't you simply strip them off your text()? (there might be a better and more secure method to strip alla carriage returns, look [here](http://blog.logiclabz.com/javascript/function-to-replace-carriage-return-to-br-in-html-textarea.aspx) for example, i just put the simplest code that came to my mind).

```
    if (e.lang != '') {
        var data = $(this).text();
        data.replace(new RegExp( "\\r", "g" ), '');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'pastebin.ashx',
            context: $(this),
            data: {
                data: data,
                lang: e.lang
            },
            success: function(t) {
                if (t.indexOf('*error*') != 0) {
                    var h = Math.floor($(this).height() * 1.62) + "px";
                    $(this).replaceWith("<iframe src='http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=" + t + "' style='border:none;width:100%;height:" + h + "'></iframe>")
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

In this way you should have the same md5

Comment: +1 Ok, this would solve the MD5 problem, but the pastebin snippet will contains no CR at all, taht's not desired.

Comment: @FelicePollano you'd still have the Line feed, isn't that enough?OR if it's not ok you could add the \r where it's missing, the idea was to standardize the text "Manually" as you have no control over how the browser interprets the text

Comment: Well, the fact is that I don't understand what is really happening, since somethimes this works on IE too.

Comment: @FelicePollano in that case you should put a check to verify that every `\n` is followed by a `\r`. If it's not, you add it. This means iterating manually on every character, but at least you'd be 100% sure that the strings are always the same

Answer (score 1):

This one should really be just a comment, but it seems I don't have enough reputation (I have no reputation at all, actually) to do it that way :)

Just a suggestion: I remember having similar problems with IE some time ago, it is possible that it's not a jQuery problem, so try to use `getElementById` and `innerText` to see if the problem remains, that would help you to restrict the field. If it's the case, try stripping away both CR and LF, in your case this should work anyway I guess.

Comment: +1, but stripping away the cr would result in a bad generated pastebin snippet...

Comment: Right, sorry but I don't know how pastebin works and I thought that MD5 generation was a different problem from the snippet itself.